# Find element above another using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find the element using jQuery from the following html.

```
<ul class="gdl-toggle-box">
   <li class="">
      <h2 class="toggle-box-title"><span class="toggle-box-icon"></span>Volunteer Form</h2>
      <div class="toggle-box-content" style="">
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

What I'm looking to do is when the h2 is clicked find the li above the h2 add a class active to it. Tried a few different calls but no luck. 
**EDIT**

The biggest issue is that there are multiple toggle boxes on a page so something like this works on pages with a single toggle but pages with multiple the result is they all open together.

```
var gdl_toggle_box = jQuery('ul.gdl-toggle-box');
gdl_toggle_box.find('li').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass('item');
});
gdl_toggle_box.find('li').not('.active').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).children('.toggle-box-content').css('display', 'none');
});
gdl_toggle_box.find('h2').click(function(){
    if( jQuery('.item').hasClass('active') ){
         jQuery('.item').removeClass('active').children('.toggle-box-content').slideUp();
    }else{
         jQuery('.item').addClass('active').children('.toggle-box-content').slideDown();
    }
});
```

Comment: it's not *above*, it's **inside**. `children` of a `parent`. Now all you can do is search SO for that exact questions.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

`closest` will match the first parent element that matches the selector traversing up the DOM tree.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yaX4V/)

```
$('h2.toggle-box-title').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: This looks really interesting. I'll take a look and give it try thanks.

Comment: This worked well and reduced the amount of code which is always great. Really stoked but I still have the issue of all the elements on the page opening.

Comment: `closest` is better than `parent` because changes to the HTML don't easily break the JS.

Comment: @rigelstpierre if you can put your html in a fiddle i can take a look at what is happening...

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$('h2.toggle-box-title').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().addClass('newclass');
});
```

Comment: .parent() for immediate parent and .parents('selector') which bubbles up until it finds a match.

Comment: @ElliotLings parents will find all matches not just the first

Comment: @wirey Will parents('selector')) bubble all the way to the root even if it finds a match?

Comment: @ElliotLings, parents() returns a collection of all parents that match the selector. Yes, you can use it to find all the parents until the root. parent() only returns a collection of 1 item.

Comment: This is the more faster way with JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

> Selecting an element's parent

In order to select an element parent, you can use the **parent()** function.

Try this:

```
$('h2.toggle-box-title').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
});
```

**to be more specific, you target the parent you would like to choose by specifying its selector*

Check the jQuery API Documentation [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

> **parent()** - Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements,
>   optionally filtered by a selector.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('h2.toggle-box-title').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

On you click in the button you can use the event:

```
$("something").parent().find("h2.myClass");
// And if you want you can add class after you find you object
```

http://api.jquery.com/find/